# Long-running I/O-bound processes in AppEngine: tasks or threads?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, asynchronous

My Python AppEngine app interacts with slow external systems (think receiving data from narrow-band connections). Half-hour-long interactions are a norm. I need to run 10-15 of such interactions in parallel.

My options are background tasks and "background threads" (*not* plain Python threads). Theoretically they look about the same. I'd stick with tasks since background threads don't run on the local development server.

Are there any significant advantages of one approach over the other?

Comment: Background threads can't hang around any longer than the request handler that spawned them.  So you would have to use a backend for longer running threads.  A Task would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: @TimHoffman: [Docs state that background threads can live longer](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/#background_threads) than the request that started them. Else I won't consider them at all.

Comment: As I said in my comment and the docs say, long running background threads can work with a "Backend" but not with for front facing requests (normal front end instances).

Comment: The runtime environment for front ends says - Threads can be created in Python 2.7 using the thread or threading modules. Note that threads will be joined by the runtime when the request ends so the threads cannot run past the end of the request. On a backend server, you can spawn a background thread; a background thread can "outlive" the request that spawns it.

Comment: @TimHoffman: just to make sure: my question is abuot the specific GAE "background threads", not plain Python threads.

Comment: You didn't t make that clear in your question, and as background threads on front ends and back ends are just python threads, the difference is life time.

Comment: OK, clarified the question a bit.

Comment: I would use tasks, and async url fetch.  That way you can have multiple http requests outstanding in single task without having to resort to threading.  Tasks have a run time of 10min.  The urlfetch still has limits on it's individual requests.  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/asynchronousrequests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how long the "interaction" takes. Appengine has a limit of 60 seconds per HTTP Requests.
If your external systems send data periodically then I would advice to grab the data in small chunks to respect the 60 seconds limit. Aggregate those into blobs and then process the data periodically using tasks.

Comment: As the question states, I need something like 30-40 minutes, and the code running at this time should better not be interrupted. Restarting where I left is possible, but restarting every 60 seconds... well, maybe will not be that wasteful. Anyway, tasks allow for 60 minutes.